# Switchable graphics vs Discrete graphics on Lenovo Legion 5

Tags: bios, uefi, lenovo-laptop, graphics

I recently made some changes in BIOS mode and I do not remember if I changed the graphics option. Now it is set to Discrete Graphics, but what was the default graphics? Searching in internet did not give me exact answer what is the difference between these two modes.

Answer (score 0):

Start in BIOS, reset BIOS to the default setup, and restart.

Now make and record any changes to BIOS that you wish.